# Double suspension on wake up

Tags: suspend, power-management, 15.10

Good morning,

I have an ASUS laptop (550 serie) with an odd behavior: when I wake it up (lid closed) I get the screen, I manage to input my password but after a few seconds it goes in suspension again, I have to turn it on via the main power switch and then it works flawlessly. What could be wrong? I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when one gets two ACPI events that seem to confuse the suspend.  I've also seen this happen when somebody manually puts the machine into suspend via the menu and then closes the lid, as this creates two suspend events too.  Are you doing the latter? If so, just try closing the lid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Colin, but when I suspend my laptop I do so by simply closing the lid. Maybe I did something wrong with the power management options?